# Php does not recognized formdata send via Ajax js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form-data

I send a Formdata with an Ajax request and try to read it in my php file. But in the php file, when i try to read what is in the $_POST with my key i see nothing. I don't understand why.

I did some research on the forum and tried to see why my code isn't working as i wanted to.

**EDIT :**

I saw the differents links but i was wondering i there is any ways to do it without JQuery.

My ajax call

```
function pageSend_DataRun ()
{
    var formElement2 = document.forms.namedItem("data_to_send_general");
    ajaxCallUrl ( "send.php",new FormData(formElement2), pageconfig_acq_generalDataCallback );
}


function ajaxCallUrl ( url, params, callback /*, ... */ )
{

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.callback = callback;
 xhr.arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 3);
 xhr.onload = ajaxSuccess;
 xhr.onerror = ajaxError;
 xhr.open( "POST", url, true );
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
 xhr.send( params );
}
```

**EDIT2 :**

I found the solution there : [[Using FormData object, the server receives an empty POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326955/using-formdata-object-the-server-receives-an-empty-post][1])

I deleted the line to "setRequestheader" in my ajax configuration and it started working.

```
    function ajaxCallUrl ( url, params, callback /*, ... */ )
    {

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.callback = callback;
     xhr.arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 3);
     xhr.onload = ajaxSuccess;
     xhr.onerror = ajaxError;
     xhr.open( "POST", url, true );

     xhr.send( params );
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the ajax call and the response processing in PHP?

Comment: you can use XMLHttprequest

Comment: based on your reference code you are not passing any `$_POST` data(s)

Comment: You need to convert your form data into a query string. This is trivial with jQuery setting "processData: false,  contentType: false" in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I edit the answer of my question in the "EDIT2" section. 
Hope it will help !